# Configure AWS Lambda to work with PHP + MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to make an `AWS` `Lambda` function run `PHP` code and `MySQL`.

For that, I followed [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/) and managed to get `PHP` working, but when I try to add my `MySQL` code I get an error. The error does not tell much, it goes like this:

```
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 14a46e73-xxx-xxx-b810-11db18dxxx0 Process exited before completing request"
```

And the log goes like

```
START RequestId: 14a46e73-xxx-xxx-b810-11db18dxxx0 Version: $LATEST
2017-02-27T19:08:12.544Z    14a46e73-xxx-xxx-b810-11db18dxxx0   SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/php.js:29:34)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
END RequestId: 14a46e73-xxx-xxx-b810-11db18dxxx0
REPORT RequestId: 14a46e73-xxx-xxx-b810-11db18dxxx0 Duration: 293.96 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 12 MB  
RequestId: 14a46e73-xxx-xxx-b810-11db18dxxx0 Process exited before completing request
```

It looks like it is complaining about an `Unexpected token F` but I can't find anything which might be causing the issue with my code, which is rather simple as I am just checking if I can connect to MySQL.

My `PHP` code is the following

```
$servername = "xx";
$username = "xx";
$password = "xx";
$dbname = "xx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


//If I remove everything above this line it works

$data = stream_get_contents(STDIN);

$json = json_decode($data, true);

$result = json_encode(array('result' => count($json)));

echo $result;
```

As you can I see I just added a simple MySQL connection to the code in the tutorial. When I remove that part, the code runs fine.

At this point, I am starting to wonder if this is even possible at all.
Any tips in the right direction will be appreciated.

php.js

```
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    //var php = spawn('php',['helloLambda.php']); //local debug only
    var php = spawn('php-7-bin/bin/php',['hello.php']);
    var output = "";

    //send the input event json as string via STDIN to php process
    php.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(event));

    //close the php stream to unblock php process
    php.stdin.end();

    //dynamically collect php output
    php.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          output+=data;
    });

    //react to potential errors
    php.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log("STDERR: "+data);
    });

    //finalize when php process is done.
    php.on('close', function(code) {
            context.succeed(JSON.parse(output));
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your lambda handler (node.js) code.  That's where the error appears to be.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I edited my question. I am using the same code in the example. I assume that code is right since in my test I am not modifying the code, I am simply trying to connect to MySQL and do nothing with it. I just wanted to make sure it worked. I am starting to think it has something to do with the way I compiled PHP.

Comment: Hmmm.  Yeah, not obvious.  Can you successfully `echo $data` right before `$json = json_decode(...`? And, if so, does it look like valid JSON?

Comment: after hours and hours, I managed to make it work. It looks like when compiling PHP using the flag --with mysql I was doing it wrong but I was not getting any error. I switched to --with mysqli and it works now. I am getting new errors, but at least the error from the question is gone. Too bad there is not a way to actually read what the errors say. Thanks for your help